# How to remove left recursion if beta contains epsilon in production rules of CFG?

Tags: parsing, grammar, context-free-grammar

Production is:

I am aware of this formula:

```
A -> A alpha | beta
```

After removing recursion:

```
A -> beta A'
A' -> alpha A' | epsilon
```

I can't understand what to do if my production in question contains epsilon as beta?
e.g. `A -> A alpha | epsilon`

Can this be the answer:

```
A -> A'
A' -> alpha A' | epsilon
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simpler solution is `A → α A | ε`. In this case, there is no need for a new non-terminal.